# UIAlertView customization, how to manage standart buttons?

Tags: iphone, button, uitextfield, uitextview, uialertview

I customize `UIAlertView` and add `UITextView` and `UITextfield`, but I need to set buttons (I add buttons in a standart `init`) to bottom of `UIAlertView` view. While `init` my `UIAlertView` I add message:`@"\n\n\n\n\n"` this give me 5 strings but when I add another one `UIAlertView` show it's standart textview. 
Take a look on image to make it more clear to understand what i have and what i need.
[image]

Comment: I think you should check Autosizing of your controllers :)

Comment: Hey can you tell me what you exactly want done. Given the space constraints, I think a modalViewController can work better in your case. Please provide more details to help understand the problem better. Is your problem that the textField is going underneath the buttons and you don't want that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Example ....

```
 // Create Alert
    UIAlertView* av = [UIAlertView new];
    av.title = @"Find";
    // Add Buttons
    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"Find & Bring"];
    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"Find & Go"];
    [av addButtonWithTitle:@"Go to Next"];
    // Make Space for Text View
    av.message = @"\n";
    // Have Alert View create its view heirarchy, set its frame and begin bounce animation
    [av show];
    // Adjust the frame
    CGRect frame = av.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= 100.0f;
    av.frame = frame;
    // Add Text Field
    UITextField* text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    text.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [av addSubview:text];
    [text becomeFirstResponder];
```